# .IFZ file conversion

Tags: extract, analysis, data-extraction

I have a lot of photos from the industrial vision system and I would like to make data analysis with it but the photos are in .ifz format.
Each photo has .ifz extension. Do you have any idea how to convert it to jpg/png or any image format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but you might be able to do this directly through the vision simulator software for your vision system. Not sure exactly which industrial vision system you are using, I cannot speak for all of them. But the one I used that stores images in .ifz format by default, there is an option "Image file save". Through this option, you pick source image(s) that are already stored in a folder (whether its on the controller or an external location; this is where your .ifz files would be) and then save to destination as desired format. If using simulator, then you'd have the .ifz files somewhere local.

Another option would be to set the vision system to output the images directly as the desired format (so instead of saving images as .ifz, save as .bmp or .jpg directly).